# RewriteCondition rewriteRule How to make All traffic direct to a single file?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

Dear folks,
Imagine a One Page Site

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1pagesite.org$  
RewriteRule ^$ 1pagesite.php [L]
```

Currently, the home page does present the 1pagesite.php correctly.

***However,*** when another file is requested say, test.php which is on the server indeed, that test.php is shown!, while I would like to point ALL and ANY trafic towards 1pagesite.php for the time being. How to make this happen sothat no other file or folder/file or anything after this domain is presented and everything is directed towards 1pagesite.php?

Thanks very much for hints and suggestions to solve this puzzle. Cheers, Sam

Comment: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ 1pagesite.php

Comment: Cool dude! thanks, place it as answer so I can treat it that way :) @Lawrence

Comment: wasn't even 80% sure i was right n got scared lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^.*(html|php)$ 1pagesite.php [L]
```

Note: This redirects only request to .html and .php pages

Comment: Thanks @Sander +1 for notifying this... Indeed... hmmm I guesse what I wish is to have *any and all* PHP and HTML pages direct to 1pagesite.php, but let other stuff be, otherwise no imges/css /folder/layout.css break as you pointed out. Cheers from Delft!

Comment: @Sam: I believe this rule would cause infinite redirection.

Comment: I have updated the rule to only redirect html/php requests. @anubhava: This should not cause an infinite redirect as the rewrite is internal, not a 301 redirect.

Comment: thanks very much, somehow this also doesnt work. IF its just my server I will be happy to accept either answer. At this moment however neither works on my Apache 2 Fedora... Any online tools you happen to know that can test redirections?

Comment: @Sam: Yes, try http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ to test your rewite rules.

Comment: @SanderMarechal Since you changed it to only redirect html/php, you should also update the note in your answer. Very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1pagesite.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !1pagesite.php$
RewriteRule \.(php|html)$ /1pagesite.php [R=302,L]
```

to redirect only php and html pages to 1pagesite.php

Comment: Thanks +1 @Anubhava but seems not to work?? I get a white page

Comment: @Sam: Before posting I had actually tested it on my local apache installation and it was working fine. I would suggest commenting out first line i.e. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1pagesite.org$ [NC]` and try again.

Comment: @Sam: I just made a minor change to include `R=302` also to make it redirect in browser also. If it still doesn't work can you `tail` your webserver's access log when you run your tests.

Comment: @Anubhava on shared hosting RewriteLog is not allowed. no particular stuff in access log either... just blanc page?! I have a feeling its the third rule thats odd `\.()` etc should there be a `^` in front? tried but wont help... strange...

Comment: @Sam: Can you pls try this `RewriteRule ^.*(php|html|htm)$ http://1pagesite.org/1pagesite.php [R=302,L]` Also try commenting out both Rewrite conditions one by one. However commenting out 2nd would cause infinite redirections but just for the sake of testing you can try that. And if you are not sure whether .htaccess is being read or not then out some junk characters in this file and you should see internal error message in your browser.

Comment: @Sander @Anubhava Thanks very much for new info, somehow it still give blank page with the new rule in place, and either comments... think I first must figure out if there is another problem...

Comment: @Sam: I will suggest first making sure your .htaccess is being read. Just put some junk text on top of your .htaccess file in DocumentRoot and see if you get internal error message in your browser.

Comment: @Anubhava, first test completed succesfully

Comment: @Sam: That is good to know at least one less thing to worry about. Now just put these lines: 

`Options +FollowSymLinks
to check whether you are getting an infinite redirection or not.

RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^.*(php|html|htm)$ http://1pagesite.org/1pagesite.php [R=302,L]`

Answer (score 1):

Your redirection only match `^$` that is to say only the root page (empty string).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1pagesite.org$  
RewriteRule ^.*$ 1pagesite.php [L]
```

So every request will be redirected to 1pagesite.php page (images, css, ... as Sander said).

If you need to filter some content you can add a

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*\.(css|jpg)$
```

to enable .css and .jpg file from your / directory to be served. This can be customized for other subdirecories files etc...